How to correctly postion size back adjusted 'continuous' data while back testing?
I'm running into issues using back-ad'justed continuous data from IQFEED while back-testing. For example, with my data, HO is priced at \$-0.002 and at a later date HO is trading around \$2.50. If the goal is to enter a position at a fixed \$ size, how can sizing be normalized so that profits aren't so skewed from trade to trade?
Direction EntryDate           ExitDate            Entry Price   Exit Price  Size
Long      2022-01-24 10:00:00 2022-09-27 07:00:00 -0.0021989    0.132080369  ?  
Long      2022-09-19 10:30:00 2022-09-21 03:00:00 2.03671785    2.251        ?

• Normalization Approach 1 - The first attempt to normalize was via a standardized MIN/MAX sizing threshold based on the average price of the dataset. With this method, the arbitrary starting size is at 10,000 units, and the max size is set at 15,000 units.
Using the table above, and with an average trade price of $1 in our dataset, we take that average price divided by the entry price (1 / 0.002) to get our multiplier (500). Then we multiply that by the standard contract size (10,000 * 500 = 5mil) and we take the lesser of the two; multiplied or the max contract size which in this case is 15,000 entry size.
For our second entry, the same applies. 1 / 2.03 ~ 0.5 as our multiplier. Take the multiplier times the standard size (0.5 * 10,000 = 5k). Then take the lesser of the two, so 5000 entry size.
The issue with this method is that the dollar size of the entries was not all consistent which could lead to bad back testing assumptions with trade outliers of bigger dollar amounts. Cleaner equity curve tho!
• Normalization Approach 2 - For our second method we attempted to cap the dollar amount of our entries at fixed \$ size (\$1k for example) and base the entries on that. So we used \$1000 / entry price => entry size. With this method, the entries occurring in the 100th decimal places were massive. Using the table above, (1000/0.002 = 500,000), our entry size is 500,000 units with a profit of $61,035 Using the table above, (1000/2.03 =500), our entry size is 500 units with a profit of \$105.21
The issue with this method is that some trades are massive outliers. Much choppier equity curve tho!
Question: How can we best normalize my entry sizes to mitigate the above-mentioned issues for back-adiusted data?
Looking for advice on if 1'm approaching this correctly or if I should head in another direction. Appreciate all of the support
Edit: I am using backtesting.py package there is no futures contract sizing for my entries. Dollar amount of entry is equal to size * entry price
Basically seeking insight on how can we best normalize my entry sizes to mitigate the above-mentioned issues for back-adjusted futures data?

Pictures are hard to read when they include a lot of text. It would be easier and quicker for others to read and understand your question if you convert it to and post it as text wherever possible.

Got the answer to my question, I will use ATR (Average True Range) to adjust my position size dynamically. See below for calculations,  hopefully this will be useful for others.

